# ListView to return a rating for each item in the list, taken from ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In brief, I want to display a list of teachers and their corresponding rating using `ListView`.

Currently, I have **`models.py`**:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Review(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Student')
    star = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    body = models.TextField()
```

In my list view, I define the `get_queryset()` function to be:

```
class IndexView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published teachers."""
        return Teacher.objects.all()[:5]
```

Now I have the object `teacher_list` which I can use in the template.

I know how to get an average rating for an individual rating using:

```
Review.objects.filter(teacher_id=self.kwargs['pk']).aggregate(Avg('star'))
```

Now I just need to change is so that I don't specify the value of `teacher_id` and include it in the `teacher_list` query set. So every teacher in `teacher_list` has `teacher.rating` attribute.

[This Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/) suggests that I can access the related models directly using the teacher object. So for teacher in `teacher_list`, I should be able to see all reviews using `teacher.star_set.all()` . I will then simply find the average of this value, and display it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to your `Teacher` model which will hold it's *average* review stars:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    # ...

    @property
    def average_review_stars(self):
        return list(self.review_set.aggregate(Avg('Sum')).values())[0]
        # self.review_set holds the reviews of the current Teacher
        # and you just aggregate the average of review stars

        # You cast the whole result to a list,
        # because dict_values does not support indexing
        # and you want the first and only value from this aggregation
```

You can have a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) in order to understand why I cast the whole thing to a list and then access `[0]`.

*Note*: Other way of doing it is `self.review_set.aggregate(Avg('Sum')).pop('stars__avg')`

Then in your template you can freely access this property:

```
<ul>
{% for teacher in teacher_list %}
    <li>Average rating: {{ teacher.average_review_stars }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```